# I keep getting HTTP Error 500.31 - ANCM Failed to Find Native Dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I recently purchased a 5$ Web Hosting Plan on interserver.net. Today I tried to publish my ASP.NET Core MVC application on the server using the Plesk interface. Then when I try to access my website, I get this error:

```
HTTP Error 500.31 - ANCM Failed to Find Native Dependencies
The specified version of Microsoft.NetCore.App or Microsoft.AspNetCore.App was not found
```

[image: Complete error screenshot]

I have already run the command `dotnet --info` command and it shows .NET Core SDK 3.1 is installed:

[image: screenshot]

Do you have any ideas about how to solve this issue?

This is what I get in the Stdout Log:

```
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version

The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '3.0.2' was not found.

  - The following frameworks were found:
      2.1.13 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
      2.1.17 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
      2.2.7 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
      2.2.8 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
      3.0.0 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
      3.1.1 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
      3.1.3 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

So apparently I have to migrate my application to the .NET Core version indicated above?

Comment: What version of ASP.NET core is your application? is it listed in the installed SDKs from the dotnet --info command?

Comment: The error message usually means it cannot find the runtime. You need to make sure you have the correct .NET core version installed on the host and/or upgrade your application to target the latest (3.1.3)

Comment: My app is .Net Core 3.0

Comment: I've just found this link from your host.... https://www.interserver.net/tips/kb/windows-hosting-net-support/.   First an most obvious thing is that the hosting package you have selected actually supports .NET core.I suspect that it possibly won't for 5$ but hey, you might have just got a great bargain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Today I solved this issue with a self-contained publishment.

> The output publishing folder contains all components of the app, including the .NET Core libraries and target runtime. The app is isolated from other .NET Core apps and doesn't use a locally installed shared runtime. The user of your app isn't required to download and install .NET Core.

For more info:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-GB/dotnet/core/deploying/#publish-self-contained

Comment: I have my deployment already made with self-contained publishment (using gitHub action on Azure). The weird thing is that it works, and after a few deployments it start to show "HTTP Error 500.31 - ANCM Failed to Find Native Dependencies".

Answer (score 2):

Please check the event viewer for more information about the issue. I had the same error and event viewer showed the following error message :
Could not find 'aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll'. Exception message:
Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.

All the necessary dlls were already installed but i realized that i had recently dowloaded a new version of aspnet core dll. But somehow my application pool was not able to recognize it. So i recreated the Application Pool and it solved the issue for me.